# Assignment to 'char' from 'const char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, qmk, qmk-firmware

I am very new to C and am encountering an issue while trying to store my `next_frame` in a variable.

If I just change the following it works fine. Only when I try to store the `next_frame` in a variable does it not compile. How can I fix it?

```
// Doesn't compile
oled_write_raw_P(next_frame, FRAME_SIZE);

// Compiles
oled_write_raw_P(frames[abs((FRAME_COUNT - 1) - current_frame)];, FRAME_SIZE);
```

Full Code

```
#define FRAME_COUNT 5 // Animation Frames
#define FRAME_SIZE 256
#define FRAME_DURATION 200 // MS duration of each frame

// Variables
uint32_t timer = 0;
uint8_t current_frame = 0;
char next_frame;

static void render_animation(void) {
    static const char PROGMEM frames[FRAME_COUNT][FRAME_SIZE] = {
        // Images here, removed for example
    };

    // If timer is more than 200ms, animate
    if (timer_elapsed32(timer) > FRAME_DURATION) {
        timer = timer_read32();
        current_frame = (current_frame + 1) % FRAME_COUNT;
        next_frame = frames[abs((FRAME_COUNT - 1) - current_frame)];

        // Set cursor position
        oled_set_cursor(128, 0);

        // Write next frame
        oled_write_raw_P(next_frame, FRAME_SIZE);

    }
}
```

These are the errors:

> error: assignment to 'char' from 'const char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
> next_frame = frames[abs((FRAME_COUNT - 1) - current_frame)];

> error: passing argument 1 of 'oled_write_raw_P' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
> oled_write_raw_P(next_frame, FRAME_SIZE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
next_frame = frames[abs((FRAME_COUNT - 1) - current_frame)]
```

does not make sense.

The variable `next_frame`, to which you are assigning a value, has the type `char`. However, you are assigning it the expression

```
frames[abs((FRAME_COUNT - 1) - current_frame)]
```

which [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the first element of the sub-array, so the expression evaluates to a value of type `const char *`.

I'm not exactly sure what you want to accomplish, but I guess the solution to your problem is to change the type of `next_frame` to `const char *`, so that the types match. In order to do this, you can change the line

```
char next_frame;
```

to:

```
const char *next_frame;
```